# Automapper: Flattening by properties naming convention does not work

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I want to flatten my data structure to dto.

My source class (simplified) looks like:

```
public class DeliveryNote
{
    public DeliveryNoteNested DeliveryNoteNestedInstance { get; set; }
    public string VehicleNo { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryNoteNested
{
    public string No { get; set; }
    public string PlantNo { get; set; }
}
```

My dto (simplified too) like

```
public class DeliveryNoteDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string No { get; set; }
    public string PlantNo { get; set; }
    public string VehicleNo { get; set; }
}
```

And then I do my mapping:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DeliveryNote, DeliveryNoteDto>());
var source = new DeliveryNote
{
    VehicleNo = "VehicleNo20",
    DeliveryNoteNestedInstance = new DeliveryNoteNested
    {
        No = "42",
        PlantNo = "PlantNo10"
    }
};
var dto = Mapper.Map<DeliveryNoteDto>(source);
```

At the end I expecting my properties No and PlantNo are filled in the dto by naming convention, but they are not.

When I do

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DeliveryNote, DeliveryNoteDto>()
                                    .ForMember(dest => dest.No, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DeliveryNoteNestedInstance.No))
                                    .ForMember(dest => dest.PlantNo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DeliveryNoteNestedInstance.PlantNo)));
```

it works, but in my real class I have close to 50 properties and I would like to avoid such boiler plate code when possible.

Comment: You could map the child objects in a foreach when the parent is mapped.

Comment: In such a case you can use Reflection to map each property

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html

Comment: @RossBush: could you explain you comment with some sample code please?

Comment: @SemenMiroshnichenko - Disregard, I thought your dto's were created as parent/child. It is your poco objects that differ from the dto's, the opposite of my comment above. This does not answer your question, however, If you create domain objects as close to the database schema as possible, minus unimportant fields. It makes crossing boundaries less of a hassle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic convention would be

```
public class DeliveryNoteDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryNoteNestedInstanceNo { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryNoteNestedInstancePlantNo { get; set; }
    public string VehicleNo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
 CreateMap(typeof(DeliveryNote), typeof(DeliveryNoteDto))
     .AfterMap((s, d) => Mapper.Map(s.DeliveryNoteNested, d));
```

Comment: For AutoMapper 8.0.0 I had to replace DeliveryNoteNested with DeliveryNoteNestedInstance in your sample code, otherwise I got compile error. After that all fields in Dto are filled with "<ProjectName>.DeliveryNoteNested", also with type name as value. So it does not work.

Comment: As before I was needed to replace DeliveryNoteNested with DeliveryNoteNestedInstance, and when I did it I get exception "Unmapped members were found <skipped exception text>
Unmapped properties:
Id
VehicleNo"

Comment: In which case I believe you have naming mismatch. if namings are different for inner object you need to map them individually with MapMember.  ex: source.Vehicle => dest.nestedObj.VehicleId cannot be mapped without using MapMember

Comment: Yes I can go this way (as I mentioned in my question), but I was looking for more elegant solution (otherwise I have to map all my 50 properties such way).